# Is there a way to make bevel size larger in Photoshop CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, photoshop-effects

I am trying to make beveled badges like such:
[image: BevelSize]

Notice how deep the bevel sizes are.

I tried making my own rendition but, the bevels come out looking really small. 
[image: My Bevel Size]

My bevel 'size' settings is maxed out on Photoshop.
[image: Settings]

So I was wondering if there is a setting or trick that I am missing to make the bevel size larger to give it a deeper look.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Any change that you can downsize the badge? It's 2592x2592px...

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no way to apply effects bigger than their maximum size. Either:

1. Recreate the effect yourself.
2. Work at a smaller scale.
3. Create your bevel at a smaller scale, convert the layer to a smart object and enlarge the smart object. Your beveled layer will be at a lower resolution than the rest of your document however.

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote? I'm happy to be wrong but as far as I'm aware I'm not

Comment: It is wrong, was trying to find a question to mark this as a dupe though but not having much luck digging it up so will probably leave a new answer in a minute.

Comment: Whew, its hard to find stuff at 6am when you have 18 pages of answers, but got it!

Comment: @Ryan scaling effects doesn't scale the *size* past it's maximum. You can even see that in your answer on the dupe. It's only increasing the *soften* value

Comment: See: [before](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xht4W.png) and [scaled](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kUlDF.png). Or [scaled with soften](http://i.stack.imgur.com/J1rDh.png)

Comment: looks like you're correct, but if you don't mind I still think this should be considered a dupe of the other so could you leave the answer over there?